# Get my current URL and insert it into html using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML that needs to be included in multiple other pages.

The HTML is like this:

```
<p>This page's URL is SOMETHING.</p>
```

I want to use Javascript to find out my current URL (window.location.href) and replace it automatically in the HTML when the page is first loaded. Something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( MAGIC LINE THAT REPLACES THE WORD 'SOMETHING' WITH THE ACTUAL URL );
});
```

So that the result is:

```
<p>This page's URL is http://www.hello.com/page3.html.</p>
```

I know how to do this with PHP but I cannot use PHP for this project, it needs to be JS. Is this even possible?

thanks very much

Comment: Thanks for everyone who has answered - I can see what you're saying but I suspect I didn't make it clear that I need to just replace "SOMETHING" with the URL. I should have said:

    <a href="SOMETHING">SOMETHING</a>

Answer (score 3):

It can be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("p").html("This page's URL is"+window.location.href);
});
```

More advanced:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        var formatStr = $("p").html();
        formatStr = formatStr.replace(/SOMETHING/i, window.location.href);
        $("p").html(formatStr);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
var url = window.location.href; 
document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = "This is current URL:" + url;
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="url"></p>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u5gpLx5x/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.url gives you the current URL in the address bar
```

. assign id to `<p id="urlHold"></p>` in your ready `jQuery('#urlHold').html(document.URL)`;